# How to hide a div after a certain scroll, if content amount is not fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Well, I am very new to web programming, I am coding a landing page where first column content is not fixed, it can be more or less.

I want to hide my CTA, once a user reaches to author info.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks for your concern.

[image]

My codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test Scroll</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .cta{
        position:sticky;
        top:600px
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Hide a div after regular amount of scroll</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="article-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        
        <br/>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="cta bg-dark py-5 text-light text-center">
         subscribe our newsletter
      </div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container author-info">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 py-3">
            <div><strong>Author name</strong></div>
            <div class="py-2"><strong>Author info:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However I tried this, but as I said scroll amount can be undefined/ depends upon content

```html
<script>

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 900 && y < 1200) {
        $('.cta').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.cta').fadeOut();
    }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a neat jQuery plugin called jQuery Visible which will deliever what you want. I added a snippet. Since I dont know what you mean by CTA, the article content will be hidden once the full author info is visible. If you pass true to the visible function the hiding starts as soon as a pixel of the div is visible.If you scroll out and everything of the div is out of screen, the other part gets shown again.
Of course you could go for your own implementation but since you are already using jQuery why not go for an existing solution.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($('.author-info').visible(true)){
   $('.article-content').hide();
  } else {
    $('.article-content').show();
  }
});

(function($) {

  /**
   * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
   * Licensed under the MIT license.
   * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
   *
   * @author Sam Sehnert
   * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
   *         the user visible viewport of a web browser.
   *         only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
   */
  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t = $(this),
      $w = $(window),
      viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
      _top = $t.offset().top,
      _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
      compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
      compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));
  };

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Test Scroll</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .cta {
      position: sticky;
      top: 600px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Hide a div after regular amount of scroll</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
  </div>
  <div style="height:200px">
    
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="article-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
          aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
          aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

          <br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
          aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="cta bg-dark py-5 text-light text-center">
          subscribe our newsletter
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container author-info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 py-3">
        <div><strong>Author name</strong></div>
        <div class="py-2"><strong>Author info:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey @Aaron, it worked but it's disappeared permanently, while refreshing it's coming again, but I wanna show and hide as per the scroll behavior, can you help?
e.g in and out